# CSS animation automatically goes to default

Tags: javascript, html, electron, chromium

https://jsfiddle.net/t3w1Lqr0/1/
When I run this code it sometimes works as expected and sometimes glitches and goes to `0deg`
See the gif Below ↓
I am using it for [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/).
I works most of the time in [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/t3w1Lqr0/1/) but rarely works in electron.
`Electron v13.1.2`
`Chromium v91.0.4472.77`
`Node v14.16.0`
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your animation purely in CSS and Utilize `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to preserve the last frame of the animation.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
div, hr::before {
  overflow: hidden; position: absolute;
  width: 10rem; height: 5rem;
}
hr {
  border-style: solid; border-width: 1.5rem;
  border-color: #333; border-radius: 10rem;
  width: 10rem; height: 10rem;
}
hr::before {
  content: '';
  transform-origin: 50% 100%; transform: translateX( -50% );
  bottom: 0.25rem; left: 50%;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  width: 0.5rem; height: 4.5rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
  animation-name: rotate; animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Force last frame of animation to stay */
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: translateX( -50% ) rotate( -90deg ); }
  100% { transform: translateX( -50% ) rotate( 90deg ); }
}
```

```html
<div> <hr> </div>
```

And if you want to add a delay before your animation starts playing as your JavaScript does you can use the CSS property `animation-delay`.

Comment: The js was there so that i can dynamically control when the meter stops! using pure css i cannot control that ! how do i stop the meter at # percentage of keystroke `rotate`

Comment: i just added that line and it works perfectly 

Comment: Shall i edit your post and add my new code!

Comment: i just added that line and changed the line `animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;` to `animation-timing-function: linear;` and it works perfectly 